# Firebird Data Provider and Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, firebird, dataprovider

I'm trying to use the Entity Framework with a Firebird database in Visual Studio 2010

Useful info:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- Firebird 2.5.0
- Firebird .Net Data Provider 2.6
- DDEX 2.0.5

I've done:

- Installed Firebird server (and it works and I can connect to a database)
- Downloaded DDEX (I've run the registry files)
- used the gacutil on the FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
  and checked that it indeed was installed and it was
- Modyfied the machine.config for both 2.0 and 4.0 in 32-bit and 64 bit folders to include the provider in the  element

When I try to add a connection in the server explorer I choose "Firebird Data Source" and the Firebird data provider and press continue. I the "Add Connection" dialog window I fill in the info "data source, database, user, password.." and press ok and then I get the following error:

> Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider

Also when I try to add a new Entity Data Model I cannot see the Firebird option.. I can only see SQL options.

I really need help on this one as I've spent many hours on this and I cannot get it to work.. I've also read other related questions on SO, but none of the suggestions I've seen seem to work for me.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.. I accidently had installed the wrong dll with gacutil.. installed the correct one and now I can use it :)